# Why does the text property overridden in user control is not showing at design time

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol which overrides the property Text. But this property is not shown at design time.

If I rename it to caption or value it is shown in properties at design time but Text is not shown.

```
public Class SomeControl
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl

    Public Overrides Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return lblText.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            lblText.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

What to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Added following attributes and the problem is solved.

```
    <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)> _
    <Browsable(True)> _
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)> _
    <Bindable(True)> _
    Public Overrides Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return lblText.Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            lblText.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Comment: It may be worth to point out, that in order to being able to use above attributes, one must also do: Imports System.ComponentModel

Answer (score 4):

The Text property is defined as:

```
[Bindable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never), Browsable(false),
 DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

Meaning, you can't browse it in the property window; you need to override the property attributes defined here (which I don't know if that will work as expected) or just set the property name to something else.

HTH.

Comment: I got the answer and posted it