# Why won't my Custom Control's Text property show up in the Properties window?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, properties, user-controls

I have a user control that inherits from UserControl. It's a button so I'm trying to make the text in the button, change-able by using the Text property like the real buttons, instead of naming my own like _Text. I have the following code but it doesn't work (ie it doesn't show up in the Property Window). The name of the label is ContentPresenter

```
public override string Text
{
    get
    {
        return ContentPresenter.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        ContentPresenter.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This thread should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873339/why-does-the-text-property-overridden-in-user-control-is-not-showing-at-design-t

Answer (score 17, accepted):

UserControl goes to significant effort to hide the Text property. From the metadata:

```
    [Browsable(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [Bindable(false)]
    public override string Text { get; set; }
```

You can make it visible by overriding those attributes in your code:

```
    [Browsable(true)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Bindable(true)]
    public override string Text 
    { 
        get { return ContentPresenter.Text; } 
        set { ContentPresenter.Text = value; } 
    }
```

I'm not promising that's enough to make it work, but it probably is.

Comment: i figured this out from Steve Wong's comment and had to translate  it to C#, and this is the code is ended up with and it worked fine, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer to this question, it helped me solve another problem I was having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899899/win-7-iis-7-5-weird-behavior-with-system-componentmodel-browseableattribute/14938911#14938911