# VS Property Grid Not Showing Class Properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

i am creating a user control in user control i create a class for storing all the properties .
and in this class i create all the properties public . and in my user control i create a properties of this class and make it public . but when i using this control in VS2012 Property Grid Not Showing Class Properties he showing me

this

> RxGrid.RxHaderPanel

This Is My Class

[image: This Is My Class]

This Is My User Control

[image: This Is My User Control]

This Is The Problem . Where S not Showing This Class As An Property and All The Sub Properties From this class

[image: This Is The Problem]

but if i use a Panel class in my user control with get set . property grid show mt all the properties of the Panel class

Please help me to solve this problem thankes

Comment: please try this link :

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180736/why-wont-my-custom-controls-text-property-show-up-in-the-properties-window][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180736/why-wont-my-custom-controls-text-property-show-up-in-the-properties-window

Comment: @DotnayTupperson thanks's i read both link but still not got the ans .

Comment: @DotnayTupperson if you see mt lest image . my property is visible in VS . but VS not allowing me to modify this and all the sub properties in this class .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whenever you create properties to be shown in the property grid in visual studio do the following steps:

Create your property:

```
private int _myProperty;
public int MyProperty 
{
 get{ return _myProperty; }
 set{ _myProperty = value; }
}
```

when you now look to the property grid, you're property will not be visible.

```
BUILD YOUR SOLUTION!
```

the property grid will not change each time you insert/update or delete properties in your code behind, you gotta build your solution always before the changes appear

Comment: I think in this case the OP wants to change the property of the custom panel from the form e.g the OP is attempting to change the value of form.RxHaderPanel.BackColor from the property grid....which as far as I know is not possible. String, int, double etc...will work fine the way you have described though